# Unable to install matplotlib for Python 3

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I'm using JetBrains PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2 (64). My Project Interpreter is either Python 3.4 or 3.5. I'm trying to install the Matplotlib package but failed every time. I succeeded on installing Networkx though.

On this site https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/tutorial/tutorial.html, in the "Drawing graphs" section, it says

> Note that the drawing package in NetworkX is not yet compatible with Python versions 3.0 and above.

Someone please confirm this? Should I install Python 2.x to use this package?
I'm doing graph modelling, if anyone can suggest other packages or advise whatever I should use, I would really appreciate. But it needs to be related to Networkx.

Comment: Why do you not trust their documentation?

Comment: Is your question about installing matplotlib or about NetworkX compatibility with Python 3?

Comment: @Goyo both xD but mainly I wanted to know if there were any other similar packages that can be used with python 3.x. Sorry for being vague about the question there.

Comment: @RemoTotoro Similar to networkx or similar to matplotlib? If `networkx.drawing` is incompatible with python3, installing matplotlib or any other package is not going to help with that. OTOH matplotlib installs and works fine in python 3 but "failed every time" does not tell us what you did, what went wrong nor how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Matplotlib, I don't see why the installation would fail.

try:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

Depending on your installation, you'll also have to install several libraries that matplotlib depends on:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev python3.5-tk tk-dev
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev g++
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install --user matplotlib
```

In addition, you will need one other package - nose. You can install it using the same syntax:

```
sudo pip3 install nose
```

Networkx installation is simple as:

```
sudo pip3 install networkx
```

Good luck!